# Capture of sys.dm_pdw_dms_workers

Tags: azure-synapse

I want to collect the data from sys.dm_pdw_dms_workers  and retain it for some amount of time.

I am running the following SQL on a near quiescent DWU6000 system and it has run for over 40 minutes.

What could be the explanation for such a long run-time?  I had executed this process on a little-used DWU100 system and the query ran in seconds.

```
INSERT INTO
     #dm_pdw_dms_workers
    (
     request_id
    ,step_index
    ,dms_step_index
    ,pdw_node_id
    ,distribution_id
    ,type
    ,status
    ,bytes_per_sec
    ,bytes_processed
    ,rows_processed
    ,start_time
    ,end_time
    ,cpu_time
    ,query_time
    ,buffers_available
    ,sql_spid
    ,dms_cpid
    ,error_id
    ,source_info
    ,destination_info
    )
select
     request_id
    ,step_index
    ,dms_step_index
    ,pdw_node_id
    ,distribution_id
    ,type
    ,status
    ,bytes_per_sec
    ,bytes_processed
    ,rows_processed
    ,start_time
    ,end_time
    ,cpu_time
    ,query_time
    ,buffers_available
    ,sql_spid
    ,dms_cpid
    ,error_id
    ,source_info
    ,destination_info
from
     sys.dm_pdw_dms_workers
where
     end_time is not null
;
```

Temp table definition is:

```
create table
     #dm_pdw_dms_workers
    (
     request_id           nvarchar(32)    /* PK of sys.dm_pdw_dms_workers. */
    ,step_index           integer         /* PK of sys.dm_pdw_dms_workers. */
    ,dms_step_index       integer         /* PK of sys.dm_pdw_dms_workers. */
    ,pdw_node_id          integer
    ,distribution_id      integer
    ,type                 nvarchar(32)
    ,status               nvarchar(32)
    ,bytes_per_sec        bigint
    ,bytes_processed      bigint
    ,rows_processed       bigint
    ,start_time           datetime
    ,end_time             datetime
    ,cpu_time             bigint
    ,query_time           integer
    ,buffers_available    integer
    ,sql_spid             integer
    ,dms_cpid             integer
    ,error_id             nvarchar(36)
    ,source_info          nvarchar(4000)
    ,destination_info     nvarchar(4000)
    )
WITH
    (
     HEAP
    ,DISTRIBUTION = hash(request_id)
    )

;
```

Source data is not large:

```
 select
     count(step_index)
 from
      sys.dm_pdw_dms_workers
 where
      end_time is not null
 ;
```

Results in

```
485,694
```

Comment: Query completed after 14 hours.  Problem is repeatable.  Working as expected on 12 other ADW databases.  Raised SR.

Comment: Hey Steve. Thanks for bringing this up and raising an SR. I'll ping the team as well.

Comment: On a subsequent 74 minute run, support staff reports the step-level timings to be: 5 MoveOperation Unspecified DMS 1:14:45 933506.  Number of rows seems trivial compared to run time of MoveOperation.

Comment: Indications are that removing the DISTRIBUTION clause of the temp table keeps a non-optimum plan from being generated at high DWUs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the DISTRIBUTION clause of the temp table keeps a non-optimum plan from being generated at high DWUs